# Comparing columns of different datatypes while concatenating in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, comparison, concatenation

I have values in a column `Period` (of datatype: `Varchar`) in `tableA` like this:

**TABLE A**

```
Period
------
3M
124W
200D
2Y
```

In Table B, column `Frequency` (datatype: `numeric`) has values like 4.0000, 154.00000, 100.00000, 4.00000 and their corresponding period code in the `Period_Code` (datatype: `Varchar`) column in the same table TableB as M, W, D, and Y.

**TABLE B**

```
Frequency      |    Period_Code
-------------------------------
4.0000         |          M
154.00000      |          W
100.00000      |          D
4.00000        |          Y
```

I can join two tables on `order_id`.

I want to compare if the the combination of `Frequency` and `Period_Code` of a record in TableB exists or does not exist in the `Period` column in TableA.

How can I do that?

It is SQL Server 2008 or later version.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just realized my answer doesn't really answer your question, but I'll leave it there temporarily before I delete in case it helps you. With your sample data, you may want to edit the values so that at least 1 record does exist between the 2 tables, as currently no combination from B exists in A.

Comment: Tanner.  my apologies for not asking the question correctly.  The two tables can be joined on order id.  and there are many same order_ids in both tables.

Comment: That sounds like important information that you _may_ want to add to the question and your sample data. I'll delete my post if it's of no further use to you now?

Comment: i still don;t get it what type is the Frequency ... numeric type in sql server will give you 4, 154, 100, 4.

Comment: you should give also an example of the output wanted ....

Comment: I just generated the create table DDL and it shows me that the data type of frequency is numeric.  That is all it says.The outputs I want are the order_ids where the matching fails.

Comment: @AOB I see this as a classic problem of asking a question in SO without  sufficient information. Nobody can help you with what you want/need unless you give enough `important` information here.

Comment: Nepali, the sufficient definition for an expert and a novice to solve a problem is different.  You never get all the information right from the beginning.  I am not hiding the information intentionally.  I provided the information in my question which I thought is important and complete, which obviously was not so complete as I know from different question.  Again, my apologies for inconvenience.

Comment: @AOB Ideally, you would want to have all your information and your attempts ready before you decide to ask a question in SO (which I understand that would not always be realistic). I feel yours might be one of those exceptions. Anyway, I have updated my answer below to hopefully meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select A.order_id, B.order_id, A.Period, B.Period_Code, B.Frequency

from   tableB B

left join tableA A on a.order_id = b.order_id

where cast(substring (A.period,1,(len(A.period)-1)) AS numeric(14,6)) <>
      B.FREQUENCY or
      upper(right(A.period,1)) <> B.Period_Code

Answer (score 0):

One question...how do you have 4.0000 as INT ?

So you have something like this:

```
    select * from tableB 
     where substring(convert(varchar,Frequency),0,charindex('.',Frequency))+Period_Code  
         in (
             Select Period
             from tableA
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code matches the desired output:

```
    DECLARE @tableA TABLE
    (
        [Period] VARCHAR(50)
    )

    DECLARE  @tableB TABLE
    (
        [Frequency] INT
    ,   [Period_Code]   VARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO @tableA
    VALUES('3M'), ('124W'), ('200D') , ('2Y')

    INSERT INTO @tableB(Frequency, Period_Code)
    VALUES(4, 'M')
    , (154, 'W')
    ,   (100, 'D')
    , (4, 'Y')

    SELECT * FROM @tableA
    SELECT * FROM @tableB

    SELECT * FROM @tableA a
    INNER JOIN
    @tableB b
    ON a.Period = CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.Frequency) + b.Period_Code
```

Comment: you can set Frequency as numeric. The result will be same as the decimal places is only 0

Comment: he has the data so no need to create tables. and also he shows that has 4.0000 in the table

Comment: In that case only the last query is useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate two fields in your tableB, you could either use `CONCAT` function (SQL Server 2012+) or just `+` (older versions). And then, to find if the concatenated field matches back to the period column in tableA, you could either do a direct `join` or use `IN` or just use `EXISTS` to accomplish your desired output:

**Join Method**

```
SELECT distinct b.*
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_id,
           frequency,
           period_code,
           convert(VARCHAR(255), cast(frequency as int)) + period_code AS period
    FROM tableB
    ) b ON a.order_id = b.order_id and a.period = b.period;
```

**EXISTS method**

```
SELECT distinct b.*
FROM tableB b
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tableA a
        WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id 
        AND a.period = convert(VARCHAR(255), cast(frequency as int)) + b.period_code
        );
```

**IN Method**

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM tableB b
WHERE convert(VARCHAR(255), cast(frequency as int)) + period_code IN (
        SELECT period
        FROM tableA a
        WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id
        );
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9113f/2/0)

Conversely, if you want to output all order_ids' where the matching fails, you could use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` to do so:

**NOT EXISTS method**

```
SELECT distinct b.order_id
FROM tableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tableA a
        WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id 
        AND a.period = convert(VARCHAR(255), b.frequency) + b.period_code
        );
```

**NOT IN Method**

```
SELECT distinct b.order_id
FROM tableB b
WHERE convert(VARCHAR(255), frequency) + period_code NOT IN (
        SELECT period
        FROM tableA a
        WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id
        );
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo2**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ba2d2/5/0)